# I want to combine XNA to Silverlight for windows phone 'mango'

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have lots of link which shows "Combine Silverlight and the XNA Framework in a Windows Phone Application"  but I am not able to figure out..
I have one project which is in "XNA" and have one Main project which is in sliver-light.
I want to add this Xna project to my main project but I am not able to..

Plz help or provide with simple steps that I will need...

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: As far i know,combine silverlight and XNA means, you are allowed to use both the silverlight and XNA assemblies in the same project/application. Earlier it was allowed.

Answer (score 3):

In the Mango version of the SDK there is a new project template for applications that use Silverlight and XNA together. There's an MSDN walkthrough on [How to: Combine Silverlight and the XNA Framework in a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202938%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) however this is for using XNA and Silverlight in the one project - I'm not sure if this will work for adding multiple projects.